# Which library to link on cygwin for getnetbyname?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, undefined-reference

I am trying to track down a larger problem and here is the simplified test case.

```
#include <netdb.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 getnetbyname("localhost");
 return 0;
}
```

I compile as:

```
$ gcc -c -Werror -Wall foo.c

$ gcc foo.o
foo.o:foo.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `getnetbyname'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc foo.o -llwres
foo.o:foo.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `getnetbyname'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc foo.o -lwsock32
foo.o:foo.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `getnetbyname'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc foo.o -lmswsock
foo.o:foo.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `getnetbyname'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc foo.o -lamIcrazy
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lamIcrazy
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Not sure where to go from here, I am pretty sure Perl uses this reference but I cannot follow the build (yet). `gcc foo.o` works on Centos 6.

Here are the .a files with the getnetbyname symbol

```
Binary file /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/CORE/libperl.a matches
Binary file /usr/lib/w32api/libmswsock.a matches
Binary file /usr/lib/w32api/libwsock32.a matches

$ nm /usr/lib/w32api/libmswsock.a --demangle | grep -B 10 getnetbyname

dqsls00019.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 i .idata$4
00000000 i .idata$5
00000000 i .idata$6
00000000 i .idata$7
00000000 t .text
         U _head_lib32_libmswsock_a
00000000 I _imp__getnetbyname@4
00000000 T getnetbyname@4

$ nm /usr/lib/w32api/libwsock32.a --demangle | grep -B 10 getnetbyname

duegs00043.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 i .idata$4
00000000 i .idata$5
00000000 i .idata$6
00000000 i .idata$7
00000000 t .text
         U _head_lib32_libwsock32_a
00000000 I _imp__getnetbyname@4
00000000 T getnetbyname@4
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not implemented, per https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/std-notimpl.html .

I must have misunderstood the exports from `libwsock32.a` and `libmswsock.a`